# XSLT Template mode - xpath evaluation

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to dynamically change the apply-templates mode based on the source XML's attribute, like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@myAttribute">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="@myAttribute"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="someOtherMode"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Is it possible to evaluate the XPath in the mode attribute?  Is there some other approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to use a dynamic value for the `mode` attribute.  It has to be static.  In your case, I would suggest doing something like this (using the name **myNode** as the context node for your example above):

```
<xsl:template match="myNode[@myAttribute = 'someValue']" mode="specialHandling">
   <!-- template contents -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="myNode[@myAttribute = 'someOtherValue']" mode="specialHandling">
   <!-- template contents -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="myNode[@myAttribute = 'aThirdValue']" mode="specialHandling">
   <!-- template contents -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="myNode[not(@myAttribute)]" mode="specialHandling">
   <!-- template contents -->
</xsl:template>
```

Then you don't even need that `xsl:choose`. You can just do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="specialHandling" />
```